# Minimum value of $\frac{\sin((2k+1)x)}{\sin(x)}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, optimization

I'm need an approximation of the minimum of the function $\frac{\sin((2k+1)x)}{\sin(x)}, k\in\mathbb{N}$.  I already tried to compute the zeros of the derivative but this looks impossible. If you plot for example the case $k=3$ so you can have an intuition of the situation you will see that it looks very evident that the minimum is reached on the first interval that the function crosses zero.

Comment: What kind of approximation do you need? (Asymptotics as $k\to\infty$, maybe?)

Comment: Interesting problem, for sure !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Suggestion:* From the known [fact](https://brilliant.org/wiki/expansions-of-certain-trigonometric-functions/), we have

$$f(x):=\frac{\sin((2k+1)x)}{\sin x}=\sum_{r=0}^{k}(-1)^r{2k+1 \choose 2r+1}\cos^{2k-2r}x \sin^{2r}x$$

Now, using the Taylor series for $\cos x$ and $\sin x$ about an arbitrary point $a$, we have

$$\sum_{r=0}^{k}(-1)^r{2k+1 \choose 2r+1}\cos^{2k-2r}x \sin^{2r}x \approx\\ \approx\sum_{r=0}^{k}(-1)^r{2k+1 \choose 2r+1}\left( 1-\frac{(x-a)^2}{2} \right)^{2k-2r}\left((x-a)-\frac{(x-a)^3}{6}\right)^{2r}$$

Not sure if this really helps in your situation, but it's a polynomial.

Comment: The exponential form of the trigonometrics, even *after taking the derivative*, would give an *exact* polynomial equation. (But the OP's intent is still unclear. That's why I'm not writing an answer myself.)

Comment: @metamorphy Yes, I agree that the OP is quite unclear with stating the exact purpose.

Comment: very helpful thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding your question, but taking the derivative of your function I get:

$f'(x) = \csc(x) \sin((2 k + 1) x)$

The derivative is a bit annoying but since I am lazy I have used a symbolic math package to find the zeros:

if $(2 k + 1) \sin((π (2 n + 1))/(2 k + 1)) \neq 0,~ x = (π (2 n + 1))/(2 k + 1), ~n \in Z$

if $\sin((2 π n)/(2 k + 1))\neq 0,~ 2 k + 1 \neq 0, ~x = (2 π n)/(2 k + 1), n \in Z$

Sorry I haven't formatted the response in the proper way...

Comment: Where's *the derivative*?

Comment: the derivative is  Csc[x] ((1 + 2 k) Cos[x + 2 k x] - Cot[x] Sin[x + 2 k x])

Comment: Just above, the second line of my answer...

Comment: And I have definitely misunderstood your question, I apologize for the intrusion. Glad you got better minds that helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, the key problem is to first locate where is located the first minimum.

We have
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin[(2k+1)x]}{\sin(x)}$$ $$f'(x)=\csc (x) ((2 k+1) \cos (2 k x+x)-\cot (x) \sin (2 k x+x))$$ To get rid of the discontinuities, multiply by $\sin^2(x)$ and, after simplifications, we are left with the problem of finding the first zero of function
$$g(x)=k \sin [2 (k+1) x]-(k+1) \sin [2 k x]$$ The minimum of $f(x)$ has to appear between two consecutive zero's; so, the first iteration of Newton method starting at the midpoint of the interval gives  the *estimate*
$$x_0=\frac{3 \pi }{2 (2 k+1)}-\frac{(k+1) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi  k}{2 k+1}\right)-k \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi 
   (k+1)}{2 k+1}\right)}{2 k (k+1) \left(\cos \left(\frac{3 \pi  k}{2
   k+1}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{\pi  (k+2)}{2 k+1}\right)\right)}$$

Using this approximation with numerical values, for "large" values of $k$
$$g(x_0)=0.0297514-\frac {0.180696} {k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$

Checking for a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{exact} \\
 2 & 0.912205 &  0.911738 \\
 3 & 0.647074 &  0.646472 \\
 4 & 0.501948 &  0.501375 \\
 5 & 0.410152 &  0.409636 \\
 6 & 0.346796 &  0.346337 \\
 7 & 0.300420 &  0.300008 \\
 8 & 0.264996 &  0.264625 \\
 9 & 0.237051 &  0.236715 \\
 10 & 0.214442 &  0.214134 \\
 11 & 0.195772 &  0.195489 \\
 12 & 0.180095 &  0.179833 \\
 13 & 0.166743 & 0.166499 \\
 14 & 0.155235 & 0.155007 \\
 15 & 0.145213 & 0.144999 \\
 16 & 0.136407 & 0.136206 \\
 17 & 0.128608 & 0.128418 \\
 18 & 0.121653 & 0.121473 \\
 19 & 0.115412 & 0.115241 \\
 20 & 0.109780 & 0.109617
\end{array}
\right)$$

This seems to be decent. Now, the approximate value of the minimum is given by $f(x_0)$.

Computing the minimum value

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{exact} \\
 2 & -1.25000 & -1.25000 \\
 3 & -1.63112 & -1.63113 \\
 4 & -2.03909 & -2.03912 \\
 5 & -2.45750 & -2.45754 \\
 6 & -2.88113 & -2.88118\\
 7 & -3.30777 & -3.30783 \\
 8 & -3.73630 & -3.73638\\
 9 & -4.16612 & -4.16620\\
 10 & -4.59683 & -4.59693 \\
 11 & -5.02821 & -5.02832 \\
 12 & -5.46009 & -5.46021 \\
 13 & -5.89236 & -5.89248 \\
 14 & -6.32493 & -6.32506 \\
 15 & -6.75774 & -6.75789 \\
 16 & -7.19076 & -7.19092 \\
 17 & -7.62394 & -7.62411 \\
 18 & -8.05726 & -8.05744 \\
 19 & -8.49070 &  -8.49089 \\
 20 & -8.92424 & -8.92444
\end{array}
\right)$$

When $k$ is large, we have
$$x_{min}=\frac{9 \pi ^2-4 }{24 \pi  }\times\frac{2k-1}{k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$ $$ f(x_{min})=-\frac{6 \pi   \cos \left(\frac{2}{3 \pi }\right)}{9 \pi ^2-4}\times(2 k+1)+O\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

**Edit**

If instead of Newton method, we use the original Halley method, we should get
$$x_0=\frac{3 \pi }{2 (2 k+1)}+\frac{(1-k) \sin \left(\frac{3 \pi }{2 k+1}\right)+(k+1) \sin \left(\frac{6 \pi 
   k}{2 k+1}\right)}{1-8 k (k+1)-k (k+1) \cos \left(\frac{6 \pi  k}{2 k+1}\right)+(7k^2+7k+1) \cos \left(\frac{3 \pi }{2 k+1}\right)}$$ which, for $k=2$ would give $x_0=0.911869$ which is a significant improvement.

Using this approximation with numerical values, for "large" values of $k$
$$g(x_0)=0.00827069-\frac {0.0503307} {k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$ which is almost $3.6$ times smaller than the previous.

When $k$ is large, we have now
$$x_{min}=\frac{9 \pi  \left(3 \pi ^2-2\right)}{8 \left(9 \pi ^2-2\right)}\times\frac{2k-1}{k^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$ $$ f(x_{min})=-\frac{2 \left(9 \pi ^2-2\right) \cos \left(\frac{6 \pi }{2-9 \pi ^2}\right)}{9 \pi
    \left(3 \pi ^2-2\right)}\times(2 k+1)+O\left(\frac{1}{k}\right)$$